# How Can I Click a ListView Item Programatically?

Tags: c#, uwp

Is this possible? UWP doesn't seem to have a `Select()` method like in WinForms. I have tried `MyListView.SelectedItem = MyListView.Items[0];`, but it only highlights the item and does not fire the `ItemClick` event, which is what I would like.

Comment: Why do you want to do that and not simply execute the code that the click handler executes?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Click handler was in a different Page class because of SplitView. Good point though. I just duplicated the code I needed that the click handler executes, and it does what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, duplication is not so good. If there's a bug, you then have 2 bugs. Follow the DRY principle of clean code.

Comment: You might want to put your navigation logic in `SelectionChanged` instead of `ItemClick` in this case 'cause you probably wouldn't want to recall the navigation when clicking on the same item.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

If I am not mistaken, ListView has a property called selected index which might do the trick. If you select the item and then were to manually call the method that the event fires you could produce the same result. I think that if selected index does not work you might just have to manually call the method and select the item you were hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the  `IsItemClickEnabled` and set it `True`.